# python ThreadPoolExecutor how does it work

Tags: python, multithreading

If I init this class with max workers like this:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
```

Can I just submit how many threads I want then? Let's say even 1k?

```
for n in range(1000): 
threads.append(executor.submit(some_function, n))
```

And it will still stick with max 20 threads at one? I am just wondering how to manage the execution of some stack of data of length X vs the multi threaded code of N threads.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it works as i said, one can provide more calls and it gets operated as soon as the queue is available.